Logstash local plugin install
I need to install plugin for clickhouse, but I don't have internet connection on my server, and Logstash is trying to find plugin from repos
I uploaded plugin to the server and tried to install it. But I can't to install it as local plugib. Logstash is always trying to find it from repos. How can I fix it?
 ./logstash-plugin install /path/to/plugin//logstash-output-clickhouse-0.1.0.gem
Using bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk
ERROR: Something went wrong when installing /path/to/plugin/logstash-output-clickhouse-0.1.0.gem, message: Failed to open TCP connection to artifacts.elastic.co:443 (execution expired)


I hope that the answer from here could help: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/airgapped-install-of-plugin-fails-trying-to-access-artifacts-elastic-co/356781/5
Try to use env LOGSTASH_PACK_URL=http://localhost:1234 when installing plugin.
